# How to make a motor capable of resisting physical movement?

Tags: motor, dc-motor, electromagnetism, control, prototyping

Is it possible to make a motor capable of resisting physical movement?

For example, at the gym you control the resistance to movement by putting more load, more weight. Is there a way to control that resistance electronically? Maybe by using a motor controller adjusting the PWM signal?

Comment: Typically you build a servo control system which acts (with limited power) to try to prevent movement.

Comment: You could, but its a lot more complicated and expensive than the non-motor methods that already exist, such as those used in rowing machines or exercise bikes: water, magnetic, fan, etc. I would also be paranoid about malfunction since the same system can rip your arms off. A lot of safety issues.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a generator as a variable load.  Use a PWM signal to short circuit the output of the generator.  Shorter duty cycle is less load, longer duty cycle is more load.

---

A generator is just a motor whose shaft is turned by an external force.

Comment: even with a Motor Controller connected is this possible? am i going to short circuit the output of the motor controller then?

Answer (score 2):

Somethink like that. If you wan't a constant torque controller then you should measure the motor current and adjust PWM duty ratio so that the motor current is equal or less the current setpoint (torque setpoint).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ1HXr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method, which you will find in a number of stair-stepper, elliptical and stationary bicycles at the gym is to use an automotive alternator. These have the advantage of a wound field, so it's possible to vary the field current, which will be much lower than the output current, by either changing the voltage applied, or use of PWM  from a fixed supply, and dissipating the generated output in a load resistor. This also has the advantage of being able to generate the supply for the control electronics and display.

With a permanent magnet machine, you would have to control the generated current, with what would effectively be a controllable constant current load.

This works for rotary motion, and for reciprocating or linear motion you can arrange some kind of linkage to translate that to rotary - the stair steppers use a chain drive. Alternatively, you could use a eddy current or hysteresis brake, where the moving element (aluminum or copper for eddy current, steel for hysteresis) passes through the magnetic field generated by an electromagnet. Transformer E laminations work well for making these.